# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi tabla tenga un estilo permanente y no cambie?

Tags: html, css, xml, odoo

estoy trabajando en un proyecto de odoo en la parte de reportes... Para eso estoy haciendo un reporte personalisado que cree...
En fin.. el detalle de la factura debe ir sobre una hoja ya pre impresa, osea que la factura ya viene con un diseño y yo lo unico que tengo que hacer es pasarle los datos.
El problema es que en mi tabla hay 3 tipos de impuestos.. 
"Impuesto al 10, al 5 y exentas". 
Cuando se carga los productos el estilo de mis "td" se ajusta al contenido que tiene dentro  y eso me esta causando problemas.
entonces mi pregunta es. Como puedo hacer que mi tabla tenga un estilo estatico y no cambie su estilo y posicion dependiendo del texto que contenga?

mi tabla

```
 <table class="mi_tabla espacios"  name="invoice_line_table">
                                <tr t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="l">
                                    <td class="quantity">
                                        <span t-field="l.quantity"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="name mitad_td">
                                        <span t-field="l.name"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="price_unit">
                                        <span t-field="l.price_unit"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="exenta">
                                        <span t-if="', '.join(map(lambda x: (x.description or x.name), l.invoice_line_tax_ids))=='exenta'" t-field="l.price_unit"/>
                                        <span t-else="">0.00</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="5">
                                        <span t-if="', '.join(map(lambda x: (x.description or x.name), l.invoice_line_tax_ids))=='impuesto 5%'" t-field="l.price_unit"/>
                                        <span t-else="">0.00</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="10">
                                        <span t-if="', '.join(map(lambda x: (x.description or x.name), l.invoice_line_tax_ids))=='impuesto 10%'" t-field="l.price_unit"/>
                                        <span t-else="">0.00</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

mi css

```
.espacios {
     border-collapse: separate;
     border-spacing: 15px 0px;
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
}
.mitad_td {
    width: 54%;
}
.mi_tabla {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 175px !important;
    left: 90px !important;
}
```

Comment: te recomendaria usar flexbox-grid y no tablas

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6658947/1595451

Comment: Me parece que la propiedad CSS clave a usar es [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), por ejemplo con el valor `hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que la propiedades clave a usar son [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), por ejemplo con el valor `hidden` y las correspondientes al tamaño máximo de las celdas, por ejemplo para el ancho máximo sería [max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/max-width).

Ejemplo:

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Frutas</th>
    <th>Animales</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Naranja</td>
    <td>Perro</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```